# How to implement matrix factorization recommender using ALS in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, recommendation-engine

I am reading the ALS algorithm paper for collaborative filtering but not sure how to implement the algorithm in Hadoop. 
Does anyone can shed some light? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can You please provide the reference to the article?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best description how to implement the ALS by yourself in distributed environment You will find in this web article - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html. The implementation there is for Apache Flink, but it shows everything: from basic understanding, naive approach, then using broadcasted matrices and blocked implementation.

For already implemented ALS solution, one I would recommend is in a Spark MLlib - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html. This implementation can be directly run on Your YARN cluster and collect the data from HDFS/Hive.

If You need to keeping Your matrix factorization latent-model up-to-date nearly online or providing online recommendation for anonymous users, then You should take a look at new Oryx Project - https://github.com/OryxProject/oryx. Which is actually called Oryx 2, this is a reincarnation of the previous Oryx but in a lambda-architecture. Good pice of nice recommender engine where You should find interesting parts for Your research.

Last but not least, I would advise doing simple PoC-implementation of ALS for single machine. Then go for a distributed implementation.

Comment: Thanks Bart, my thinking is the following. By ALS, there is step to update M and update U. The calcuation of M can be impleted by map-reduce. Each mapper calculate a column of M and the reducer can assembly the M matrix. After getting M, the same map-reduce approach can be used to calcualte U. The thing is that I may need a lot of iterations before it converges.